# JavaScript: How to add to values from an array to object properties which are from different array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Where am I going wrong?
I was working on something. And I am facing this problem.

```
let array1 = [{
      id: 1,
      profile: ''
    }, {
      id: 2,
      profile: ''
    }, {
      id: 3,
      profile: ''
    }]

let array2 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

array1.forEach(function(value) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    return value['profile'] = array2[i]
  }
})

console.log(array1);
```

required output:

```
array1 = [{id:1, profile: 'name1'}, {id:2, profile: 'name2'}, {id:3, profile: 'name3'}]
```

I tried below code:

```
array1.forEach(function(value) {
  for(let i=0; i<array2.length; i++){
    return value['profile'] = array2[i]
  }
})
```

But I am getting the following output:

```
[ { id: 1, profile: 'name1' },
  { id: 2, profile: 'name1' },
  { id: 3, profile: 'name1' } ]
```

Please guide me!

Comment: Don't nest two loops. You want to assign `array1[0].profile = array2[0]`, `array1[1].profile = array2[1]` and so on.

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < array1.length;i++)
 array1[i].profile = array2[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling a for loop inside the forEach loop you are actually changing each array1 item profile properties multiple times. If you just want to use the same index to copy one value from one array to the other, the forEach method handler takes the current index as second argument. Here is an example:

```js
let array1 = [{
  id: 1,
  profile: ''
}, {
  id: 2,
  profile: ''
}, {
  id: 3,
  profile: ''
}]
let array2 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

array1.forEach(function(value, i) {
  value['profile'] = array2[i]
})

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

he code you shared is confusing a couple of concepts up which may be leading to your problem.

- Array.forEach does not take a return value
- mutating existing variables often leads to bugs
- you are also looping round the whole of the 2nd array and always setting array value 1 to the result.

instead, let's use `.map` to fix those issues.

```
const array1 = [{id:1, profile: ''}, {id:2, profile: ''}, {id:3, profile: ''}]
const array2 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
const array3 = array1.map(function (array1Item, index) {
   return {
      ...array1Item,
      profile: array2[index],
   };
});
```

here we are never mutating, or changing, existing data. Within the map we use `...` to create a shallow-copy of the array item to ensure that array1 never changes.  This makes the code easier to maintain and read in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You must try this this will work for you

```
let array1 = [{id:1, profile: ''}, {id:2, profile: ''}, {id:3, profile: ''}]
let array2= ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

 array1 = array1.map((i , index) =>{
    return i.profile=array2[index]
})

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Never really makes sense using `map()` when you don't intent to use the new array it returns

Comment: @charlietfl it modifies the same  array